# Coloring ) in listing

Tags: listings

I'm trying to create a style using for coloring `\` and brackets in code sample (PStricks) using the `listings` package; I tried using the answer given by Marco Daniel in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44969/color-and-in-listings-environment) using `literate` for colors in `( )` but, it did not work in my case, as it only colors `(` and not `)`. This is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{beramono}
\definecolor{colKeys}{rgb}{0,0,1}
\definecolor{colIdentifier}{rgb}{0,0,0}
\definecolor{colString}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}
% Create a personal style colorate \ 
\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{%
    language=PSTricks,%
    texcsstyle=*\color{blue},
    keepspaces=true,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\small, %
    identifierstyle=\color{colIdentifier}, %
    keywordstyle=\color{colKeys}, %
    morekeywords={psrotate},
    stringstyle=\color{colString}, %
    commentstyle=\itshape\color{gray}, %
    columns=flexible, %
    keywordstyle=[2]\color{Purple}, %
    morekeywords=[2]{showgrid,nodesep,linecolor,dotscale,linewidth,unit,showpoints},
    deletekeywords=[1]{begin,end,pspicture,endpspicture},%
    keywordstyle=[3]\color{NavyBlue}, %
    morekeywords=[3]{begin,end,pspicture,endpspicture},
    keywordstyle=[4]\color{Orange}, %
    morekeywords=[4]{psEllipseTangents},%
    extendedchars=true, %
    showspaces=false, %
    showstringspaces=false, %
    breaklines=true, %
    breakautoindent=true, %
    xleftmargin=0pt,
    literate=*{\{}{{\textcolor{NavyBlue}{\{}}}{1}
        {\}}{{\textcolor{NavyBlue}{\}}}}{1}
        {[}{{\textcolor{NavyBlue}{[}}}{1}
        {]}{{\textcolor{NavyBlue}{]}}}{1}
        {(}{{\textcolor{NavyBlue}{(}}}{1}
        {)}{{\textcolor{NavyBlue}{)}}}{1}%
}[tex] % need for \ color
\lstset{style=mystyle}
\begin{document}
First
\begin{lstlisting}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=true](10,10)
\psdot(2,4) % a simple dot
\psellipse(7,7)(3,1.5)
\psEllipseTangents(7,7)(3,1.5)(2,4)
\pcline[nodesep=-1cm,linecolor=blue](2,4)(EllipseT1)
\pcline[nodesep=-1cm,linecolor=blue](2,4)(EllipseT2)
\psdots(EllipseT1)(EllipseT2)
\uput[-80](EllipseT1){T1}
\uput[115](EllipseT2){T2}
\end{pspicture}
\end{lstlisting}
Second
\begin{lstlisting}
\pspicture(-0.5,-3.5)(8.5,4.5)
\psset{unit=0.75}
\psaxes{->}(0,0)(-0.5,-3)(8.5,4.5)
\psdots[linecolor=red,dotscale=1.5](2,1)
\endpspicture
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a [known issue](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73795/problem-with-literate-and-breaklines-true-in-listings-package) with `listings`: setting `breaklines` to `true` breaks any literate replacement that involves the closing parenthesis.

[image]

Fortunately, under the assumption that no backtick occurs in your listings, you can remedy the situation by applying this patch (adapted from [this answer by egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/73867/21891))

```
\patchcmd{\lsthk@SelectCharTable}{`)}{``}{}{}
```

[image]

Note: if needed, the patch can be undone with

```
\patchcmd{\lsthk@SelectCharTable}{``}{`)}{}{}
```

### Complete code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{beramono}
\definecolor{colKeys}{rgb}{0,0,1}
\definecolor{colIdentifier}{rgb}{0,0,0}
\definecolor{colString}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}
% Create a personal style colorate \ 
\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{%
    language=PSTricks,%
    texcsstyle=*\color{blue},
    keepspaces=true,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\small, %
    identifierstyle=\color{colIdentifier}, %
    keywordstyle=\color{colKeys}, %
    morekeywords={psrotate},
    stringstyle=\color{colString}, %
    commentstyle=\itshape\color{gray}, %
    columns=flexible, %
    keywordstyle=[2]\color{Purple}, %
    morekeywords=[2]{showgrid,nodesep,linecolor,dotscale,linewidth,unit,showpoints},
    deletekeywords=[1]{begin,end,pspicture,endpspicture},%
    keywordstyle=[3]\color{NavyBlue}, %
    morekeywords=[3]{begin,end,pspicture,endpspicture},
    keywordstyle=[4]\color{Orange}, %
    morekeywords=[4]{psEllipseTangents},%
    extendedchars=true, %
    showspaces=false, %
    showstringspaces=false, %
    breaklines=true, %
    breakautoindent=true, %
    xleftmargin=0pt,
    literate=*{\{}{{\textcolor{NavyBlue}{\{}}}{1}
        {\}}{{\textcolor{NavyBlue}{\}}}}{1}
        {[}{{\textcolor{NavyBlue}{[}}}{1}
        {]}{{\textcolor{NavyBlue}{]}}}{1}
        {(}{{\textcolor{NavyBlue}{(}}}{1}
        {)}{{\textcolor{NavyBlue}{)}}}{1}%
}[tex] % need for \ color
\lstset{style=mystyle}

\usepackage{etoolbox} % provides the \patchcmd macro
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\lsthk@SelectCharTable}{`)}{``}{}{} % patch listings
%\patchcmd{\lsthk@SelectCharTable}{``}{`)}{}{} % undo patch if needed
\makeatother

\begin{document}
First
\begin{lstlisting}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=true](10,10)
\psdot(2,4) % a simple dot
\psellipse(7,7)(3,1.5)
\psEllipseTangents(7,7)(3,1.5)(2,4)
\pcline[nodesep=-1cm,linecolor=blue](2,4)(EllipseT1)
\pcline[nodesep=-1cm,linecolor=blue](2,4)(EllipseT2)
\psdots(EllipseT1)(EllipseT2)
\uput[-80](EllipseT1){T1}
\uput[115](EllipseT2){T2}
\end{pspicture}
\end{lstlisting}
Second
\begin{lstlisting}
\pspicture(-0.5,-3.5)(8.5,4.5)
\psset{unit=0.75}
\psaxes{->}(0,0)(-0.5,-3)(8.5,4.5)
\psdots[linecolor=red,dotscale=1.5](2,1)
\endpspicture
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Many Thanks (again) ...sorry for duplicate answer ... (i don't see related post before).

Comment: @PabloGonzálezL No problem. Duplicates are not always easy to find. Don't hesitate to upvote my answer as well `:p`