# Inconsistent style of "other keywords" when breaklines=true

Tags: formatting, listings

Some keywords defined with the `otherkeywords` key are not formatted as expected when `breaklines` is set to `true`. Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
  basicstyle=\itshape\ttfamily, 
  keywordstyle=\upshape,
}
\lstdefinestyle{syntax}{
  language=[ANSI]C,
  otherkeywords={(,)},
  breaklines=true,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[style=syntax]
  const ( int | float ) text
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

The result looks something like this (but nicely monospaced...):

const ( int | float *)* *text*

If I set breaklines=false, it looks as expected:

const ( int | float ) *text*

Am I missing something obvious? As for versions, "This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (MiKTeX 2.9)" on Windows (at work, they force me...).

Comment: Literate replacements and "other keywords" that involve the closing-parenthesis character `)` are known to be affected by breaklines. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73795/problem-with-literate-and-breaklines-true-in-listings-package and its accepted answer for a workaround.

Comment: and [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: also related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172945/coloring-in-listing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/149203/36296

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\lstset{
    basicstyle=\itshape\ttfamily, 
    keywordstyle=\upshape,
}

\lstdefinestyle{syntax}{
    language=[ANSI]C,
    breaklines=true,
    otherkeywords={(,)},
}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\lsthk@SelectCharTable}{)}{`}{}{} 
\makeatother 

\begin{document} 
    \begin{lstlisting}[style=syntax]        
const ( int | float ) text 
    \end{lstlisting}               
\end{document}
```

[image]