# Color problem in listings with breaklines=true

Tags: color, listings

I'm trying to highlight a specific comment type with `lstsliting`, and the option `breaklines` messes things over.

Here is the faulty output :
[image: Faulty output]

The color purple (produced by the keyword `name`) takes over, and colors the rest of the listing.

Here is what I need (and hat should normally produce) in terms of colors  :
[image: Desired output]

Here is the MWE :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[]{geometry}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames,usenames,table]{xcolor} % Smart color names
\usepackage{listings}


\lstdefinestyle{system}{%
%    breaklines=true,   % <-- This makes the color scheme go nuts
    breakatwhitespace=true, % <-- Even with this
    keywordstyle=\color{Blue},
    basicstyle=\normalfont\ttfamily,
    morecomment=[s][\color{Blue}]{[*}{]},
    morecomment=[s][\color{Green}]{[+}{]},
    morecomment=[s][\color{Red}]{[-}{]},
    morecomment=[n][\color{Purple}]{(name:}{)},
    morecomment=[n][\color{Gray}]{(domain:}{)},
}


\begin{document}


\begin{lstlisting}[style=system]                  
test      X:445 Test     [+] Success1        (name:system)   (domain:web)
test      X:445 Test     [-] Failure 10.0    (name:system)   (domain:web)
test      X:445 Test     [*] Don't know 10.0 (name:system)   (domain:web)
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Does anybody know why the `breaklines` options messes the colored filter ?
In the content of the listing, I can't get rid of all the spaces, so removing them to avoid a line break is not an option.

I want to be able to have the colored filters AND the line break.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/186225/28926), the solution is to patch the command `\lsthk@SelectCharTable`.

The corrected MWE is thus :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[]{geometry}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames,usenames,table]{xcolor} % Smart color names
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\lsthk@SelectCharTable}{)}{`}{}{} 
\makeatother 


\lstdefinestyle{system}{%
    breaklines=true,
    breakatwhitespace=true,
    keywordstyle=\color{Blue},
    basicstyle=\normalfont\ttfamily,
    morecomment=[s][\color{Blue}]{[*}{]},
    morecomment=[s][\color{Green}]{[+}{]},
    morecomment=[s][\color{Red}]{[-}{]},
    morecomment=[n][\color{Purple}]{(name:}{)},
    morecomment=[n][\color{Gray}]{(domain:}{)},
}


\begin{document}


\begin{lstlisting}[style=system]                  
test      X:445 Test     [+] Success1        (name:system)   (domain:web)
test      X:445 Test     [-] Failure 10.0    (name:system)   (domain:web)
test      X:445 Test     [*] Don't know 10.0 (name:system)   (domain:web)
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

And the output is properly colored :

[image: MWE output]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the best solution, but it does work if you remove the ambiguity in the closing delimiter:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames,usenames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstdefinestyle{system}{%
    breaklines=true,
    keywordstyle=\color{Blue},
    basicstyle=\normalfont\ttfamily,
    morecomment=[s][\color{Blue}]{[*}{]},
    morecomment=[s][\color{Green}]{[+}{]},
    morecomment=[s][\color{Red}]{[-}{]},
    morecomment=[n][\color{Purple}]{(name:}{m)},
    morecomment=[n][\color{Gray}]{(domain:}{b)},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[style=system]                  
test      X:445 Test     [+] Success1        (name:system)   (domain:web)
test      X:445 Test     [-] Failure 10.0    (name:system)   (domain:web)
test      X:445 Test     [*] Don't know 10.0 (name:system)   (domain:web)
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Thanks ! But since I can only base the code on the delimiter itself `)` and not the delimiter + its previous char, this answer does not address the issue I have, IMHO.