Allowing line breaks in listings causes parenthesis to lose their color
I am trying to create a listings style to highlight LaTeX codes. Enabling breaklines seems to remove customized color in literate option

The same issue is reported in Problem with literate and breaklines=true in listings package. TikZ manual is typeset while this issue is not seen in their examples
Using {~)}{{\textcolor{SlateBlue3}{)}}}{1} (replacing ) with ~) in the source code) works. It is suggested in
How to change style for right parenthesis inside lstlisting environment
However, attempting to replace the source code is suboptimal
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}

\usepackage{listings}
% BEGIN_FOLD

\lstdefinestyle{LaTeX}{
basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize, % font style and size
breaklines=true, % allows breaking long lines
literate=
*{\{}{{\textcolor{IndianRed1}{\{}}}{1} % {
 {\}}{{\textcolor{IndianRed1}{\}}}}{1} % }
 {[}{{\textcolor{SpringGreen3}{[}}}{1} % (
 {]}{{\textcolor{SpringGreen3}{]}}}{1} % ]
 {(}{{\textcolor{SlateBlue3}{(}}}{1}   % (
 {)}{{\textcolor{SlateBlue3}{)}}}{1},  % )
}

% END_FOLD

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[style=LaTeX]
{} () []
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}


@Marijn If better answers to the same problem are the goal, a bounty would make more sense then posting yet another question and spreading out the information across multiple places.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz looking through the duplicate questions for https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73795/problem-with-literate-and-breaklines-true-in-listings-package I found https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172945/coloring-in-listing which is actually much clearer - it doesn't have the disclaimer of egreg that it might break things but given that nobody complained in the past 10 years it is probably fine, so I have cast the final closevote using that one as a target.

@Marijn Nice find!
