# Highlight certain texts in listings or minted

Tags: listings, bold, highlighting, minted

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Manual highlight of TeX code in a verbatim environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41720/manual-highlight-of-tex-code-in-a-verbatim-environment)

I want to highlight certain parts of a program output listing which represent user input. For example I want to use `\textbf` in this way:

```
$ \textbf{dmesg | tail}

...
[ 6854.215650] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 0b 00 00 08
[ 6854.215653] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 6854.215659] sdc: sdc1
[ 6854.218079] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
[ 6854.218135] sd 7:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
...
```

I am unable to do it in `listings` and `minted`. Moreover I can't find a list of supported languages by minted in order to set it to bash output.

Comment: `minted` uses a Python Pygments library. Look there for a list of supported languages.

Comment: Thanks, [this](http://pygments.org/languages/) is the page.. By the way I cannot make `\textbf` work inside `minted` block.

Comment: For a list of supported languages, use `pygmentize -L lexers`.  `:)`

Comment: Since I can't comment yet I'll write this as an answer, I hope this is not too inappropriate: This seems to be a near duplicate of this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41724/14576 There the solution was to use a laslisting environment, and do the formatting with the literate option \lstset

Comment: Hi Francesco. Please take a look at [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15237/highlight-text-in-code-listing-while-also-keeping-syntax-highlighting/49309#49309) and report if there is anything else you need. The answers partly provide pretty sophisticated ways of highlighting, but [this one](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19250/3751) shows how to use the `moredelim` option of listings to apply simple font commands, such as `\bfseries` to highlight certain parts.

Comment: I'll keep it as reference, thanks. I have found a solution in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704072/how-do-i-emphasize-parts-of-an-lstlisting) by inserting `\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{cmtt}{bx}{n}{<5><6><7><8><9><10><10.95><12><14.4><17.28><20.74><24.88>cmttb10}{}` and using
`\begin{lstlisting}[escapechar=@]@\textbf{text}@
\end{lstlisting}`

Comment: @AndreasWallner: You have now over 50rep so you can comment everywhere. Please note that you can also flag a post as a duplicate using the 'flag' link below the post.

Comment: @MartinScharrer thanks for the cleanup, did you "move" my answer to be a comment? I noticed it's already there when I wanted to write it again... Thanks though, didn't think it would be that fast to be able to comment

Comment: @AndreasWallner: Yes, I converted your post to a comment. This is standard procedure in such cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a fast solution in an answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704072/how-do-i-emphasize-parts-of-an-lstlisting). I had to add

```
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{cmtt}{bx}{n}{<5><6><7><8><9><10><10.95><12><14.4><17.28><20.74><24.88>cmttb10}{}
```

and write my code block in this way (using listings)

```
\begin{lstlisting}[escapechar=@]
$ @\textbf{dmesg | tail}@ 

...
[ 6854.215650] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 0b 00 00 08
[ 6854.215653] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 6854.215659] sdc: sdc1
[ 6854.218079] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
[ 6854.218135] sd 7:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
...
\end{lstlisting}
```